# Which formal theory is commonly used to describe mathematical analysis?

Tags: analysis, logic, first-order-logic, axioms

I'm not sure, whether there is a commonly used and sort of outstanding one. If there was such, it would be incredibly easy to google. Or at least all Analysis books would've been mentioning that the subject is based on this particular formal first-order theory that everyone uses.

Comment: Set theory suffices.

Comment: @VioletFlame that makes sense. And should've made sense to me before asking that question (

Comment: Most analysts use $\sf ZFC$ and have little to no motivation to delve any deeper into the foundations or worry about whether or not weaker systems can be used

Comment: It seems to me that analysts have more or less had to discreetly improvise their own set theory and logic. Ease of use doesn't seem to have been a consideration in the development of ZFC and FOL theory. Analysts want to be able, for example, to quantify over sets and functions. They also have no use for the FOL notion of an overarching, non-empty domain of discourse.  Quantifiers even within the same statement may be restricted to different, possibly empty domains. Most introductory analysis textbooks have a "chapter 0" on any required set theoretic fundamentals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of analysis can be developed  within $\mathsf{ZFC}$ set-theory, as can almost all of modern mathematics.This isn’t mentioned in most analysis books, because most analysts probably don’t care too much about foundations, and they’d probably accept any foundation that lets them make their arguments.